Cycles and OSL : how to implement a custom closure
I'd like to implement a custom shader in OSL (Open Shading Language) to reproduce the Hapke reflectance model (it allows to visualize the opposition surge effect, visible on the moon for example).
I have seen that it has been done in some scientific papers (see paper references below). But when I try to reproduce it I face a problem: even if I can write the reflectance BRDF function in my script, the float value obtained from it is not sufficient to obtain a rendering. I also need to integrate it through all the incidence angle possible (see Rendering Equation).
This integral is usually done through the use of closures in Blender cycles, if I understood well. But only a few closures are available, such as Lambertian or Oren-Nayar (corresponding in OSL to the method diffuse(N)). They would not fit my need, as Hapke's brdf function (f_r in the Rendering Equation) is dependent on the incidence angle and must be part of the integral, not multiplied afterwards to the integral result.

Do you know how I could create a custom closure in Blender Cycles? Knowing that I can have through nodes and drivers the input light incidence and the camera position.
If not, do you think I could use an existing closure to come close to the result I need?
Thanks in advance!

Paper references:

J. Villa, J. W. McMahon, et I. A. Nesnas, « IMAGE RENDERING AND TERRAIN GENERATION OF PLANETARY SURFACES USING SOURCE-AVAILABLE TOOLS »
L. Matthies et al., « Lunar Rover Localization Using Craters as Landmarks ».


Hi I think to do this you'll need to create your own closure, which means creating your own personal fork of blender. I've done this but I haven't made the git-repo with my code public because I'm still tweaking things. But here's a list of the files you'll need to add/change code for to create your own closure:
Modified: intern/cycles/blender/shader.cpp
Modified: intern/cycles/kernel/CMakeLists.txt
Modified: intern/cycles/kernel/closure/bsdf.h
Added: intern/cycles/kernel/closure/bsdf_(your_closure).h
Modified: intern/cycles/kernel/osl/closures_setup.h
Modified: intern/cycles/kernel/osl/closures_template.h
Modified: intern/cycles/kernel/osl/shaders/CMakeLists.txt
Added: intern/cycles/kernel/osl/shaders/node_(your_closure).osl
Modified: intern/cycles/kernel/osl/shaders/stdcycles.h
Modified: intern/cycles/kernel/svm/closure.h
Modified: intern/cycles/kernel/svm/types.h
Modified: intern/cycles/kernel/types.h
Modified: intern/cycles/scene/shader_nodes.cpp
Modified: intern/cycles/scene/shader_nodes.h
Modified: scripts/startup/bl_ui/node_add_menu_shader.py
Modified: source/blender/blenkernel/BKE_node.hh
Added: source/blender/gpu/shaders/material/gpu_shader_material_(your_closure).glsl
Modified: source/blender/makesdna/DNA_node_types.h
Modified:
source/blender/makesrna/intern/rna_nodetree.cc
Modified: source/blender/nodes/NOD_static_types.h
Modified: source/blender/nodes/shader/CMakeLists.txt
Modified: source/blender/nodes/shader/node_shader_register.cc
Modified: source/blender/nodes/shader/node_shader_register.hh
Added: source/blender/nodes/shader/nodes/node_shader_bsdf_(your_closure).cc
I would reference the Diffuse bsdf when it comes to looking at code. And then you can use the git logs for the toon bsdf for seeing what changes need to be made to add a new closure. It's a lot of code to take into account and understanding the git logs can be tricky since file names and locations have changed over the years since toon bsdf was first added to blender.
If you're still having a hard time adding your closure, I'll try and remember to post a link to my git-repo for my version of blender once I make it public. That will have the exact changes in each file you need to make to make your own closure.
I wish you the best of luck,
Nate
